# Windows ASLR just at boot time

Tags: windows, operating-system, portable-executable, exploit, aslr

In few articles I read that Windows ASLR randomizes the addresses of whole system **just at boot time** in contrast to Linux where ASLR randomizes addresses of every process when executed.

Does it's true ?
Why does it's work like this in windows ? we are able to predict the functions addresses and exploit it (when in linux we have to calculate at runtime the function address based on ASLR randomization).

What is the reasons to this ?
There is any benefits ?

Comment: Can you give links or references to these articles?

Comment: https://www.abatchy.com/2017/06/exploit-dev-101-bypassing-aslr-on.html


https://www.symantec.com/avcenter/reference/Address_Space_Layout_Randomization.pdf



Search `boot` key word (ctrl+f)

@OrtomalaLokni